# Mirror SVN Repository [Write-through proxying]

Tags: svn, proxy, mirror, write-through

I have a codebase located in Europe and access this codebase from Asia. Codebase is substantially huge, downloading the whole codebase (which is required sometimes) becomes a pain.

I wanted to know whether anything like this.

I want a solution that *"I will have a svn server locally which will sync with the main svn and serve my team as the svn is locally hosted."*

Thanks in advance
Munim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Multisite Repository Replication](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/multisite-replication/) with VisualSVN Server. That's exactly what you were looking for then.

Multisite Repository Replication enables classic master/slave replication architecture which allows you to setup a master repository at your main codebase location in Europe with multiple slaves at other locations.

In contrast to standard write-through proxy solution, in Multisite Repository Replication feature

- master and slave repository looks and acts just like a regular **writeable** Subversion repository,
- the replication between master ans slaves is performed automatically and transparently,
- supports advanced authentication mechanisms,
- It's easy to setup, works out-of-the-box with minimal configuration via VisualSVN Server Manager MMC console.

Learn more at http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00068/

Comment: thanks. This will definitely help people stopping by and still using SVN. I guess git addressed most of the svn problems and people moving towards it.

Answer (score 13):

You can also try a write-through-proxy which is supported since SVN 1.5 and works fine.

With this setup you have a master and a slave repository.

The slave repo acts as a local read cache while commits will be proxied to your master server and synced back.

This solution comes with subversion / apache.

See this [svndevelopers blog](http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/2007/10/yesterday-at-th/)  for more details. Or the [superb SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.writethruproxy), or last but not least the [subtrain admin training](http://subtrain.tigris.org) presentations

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Can you give me detail how to do it?

Comment: It is not a difficult task, but you have to do a lot of things (apache configs and subversion hooks) You can use the links as references (I added two more references)

Comment: is there an updated link that works for the SVN developer blog?  It seems like they have some authentication required now (not obvious how to register or anything like that)

Comment: Updated link vor svn 1.7 redbook: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.writethruproxy

Comment: Updated link for the blog post: http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/yesterday-at-th

Answer (score 3):

Here is a pretty good article on how to set this up:

http://wordaligned.org/articles/how-to-mirror-a-subversion-repository

The general idea is to use `svnadmin hotcopy` to do the copy without down time, perhaps triggered by a post-commit hook, or on a timer.

Another option, discussed here:

http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/2007/08/mirroring-repos/

Is to use SVN sync to do a sync, rather than a copy, using the `svnsync synchronize` command.

Comment: Sorry! This is the first post on Google when you search with **Mirror SVN Repository**. I have edited the question, please check the question again. I am sure you can help me on this.

Comment: Ok, `svnsync` is almost definitely your way to go then.  You can set up a post-commit hook that will do the syncing for you.  That second link should give you a pretty good walk-through.

Comment: Perhaps `svnsync` could be a solution, but I want some that is similar to `TFS Proxy`.

Comment: @Munim: I don't think that there is a caching proxy server for SVN.  I think `svnsync` is the closest you are going to get.  You can get reasonably close using scvsync, tho.

Comment: There is the write-through proxy mechanism which is build into svn1.5(however with some apache magic, you can get it running on svn 1.4: http://www.rvo-consulting.com/2008/02/21/subversion-diy-write-through-proxy/ )

Answer (score 0):

Besides the svnsync, you can try the commercial solution from Wandisco.