# Slow remote SVN. Fix?

Tags: svn

I'm working with a very remote SVN that is pretty slow. My internet connection is good but the distance plays its part. It's not that slow, I can work. But it pisses me off when every diff takes a second or two.

Is there a way to create a proxy SVN locally that constantly downloads the remote one?

Should I use local git or mercurial? They can bind to a SVN and can clone it.

I need something that doesn't need much effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a local SVN mirror that stays in sync with the main repository, but create it as a write-through proxy, which means that when you try to commit the change actually gets forwarded to the master server then your server gets a copy of the change.

More info here: [Mirror SVN Repository [Write-through proxying]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286586/mirror-svn-repository-write-through-proxying)

Comment: Is there an easy way to do this on mac that can be easily transportable/reproducible? Maybe I should write another question...

Comment: It's a bit of a heavyweight solution that is better suited to situations where one team uses SVN and a remote team needs access across a slow/high latency network.  If you need a solution just for yourself then you could try [git-svn](http://andy.delcambre.com/2008/03/04/git-svn-workflow.html)

Comment: git changes the way i should think about source control. I don't want that yet.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember Subversion keeps the original (checked out/updated) file locally and performs the diffs locally. An `svn diff` does not involve network. A proxy would be difficult but you think to mirror the repository locally.

Comment: Maybe I was diff-ing with older versions. I don't remember.

Comment: Voted down, this misses the point - many operations require network access with subversion - obviously the questioner is using those operations.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that a proxy SVN server has been done, since this would basically mean that a distributed version control system would have to be implemented, which is outside SVN's scope.
git or mercurial are your best choices, since they support these features out of the box.

Comment: It gets too complex with Mercurial for a single user.