# Moving remote subversion server to a new local subversion server

Tags: svn

I'm currently working with a remote svn server. However sometimes I have to work offline (because the remote server is on a closed network there is no connection to internet). What I want to do is to copy the svn server to my local server (a.k.a my Laptop).

I should probaly setup a local subversion server (as mentioned here: http://www.subversionary.org/howto/setting-up-a-subversion-server-on-ubuntu-gutsy-gibbon-server)

However what should I do **to copy the remote subversion server to my local laptop?** I mean a simple svn checkout is not what I want. I want a replicate of the remote server, but it should be running in my own laptop server.

Actually think of moving(copying) the subversion server to another location. I just don't know where to begin. Any keywords or how to begin explanations would be helpful.

Also note, that I can commit and checkout from the svn server, but I probably don't have any administrator rights to acces the remote servers shell,etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only can access the remote subversion repository via the subversion protocol, you can still use `svnsync` to create a copy of the repository:

```
svnadmin create /tmp/svn
ln -s /bin/true /tmp/svn/hooks/pre-revprop-change
svnsync init file:///tmp/svn https://svn.example.org/svn/my-project
svnsync sync file:///tmp/svn
rm /tmp/svn/hooks/pre-revprop-change
```

Comment: I moved it under /var/svn (this was my question) and setup a local svn server (what I wanted with my local svn repo) according to this tutorial: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60736/how-to-setup-a-subversion-svn-server-on-gnu-linux-ubuntu/60792#60792. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to use the Subversion [write-through proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286586/mirror-svn-repository-write-through-proxying). This means that you have a local repository that is kept in sync with the master when you are online, but if you try to commit then your local mirror will forward the request to the master and then re-sync. Note that there is no way of being able to commit when you aren't online.  If you want a way of saving local changes while you're offline then you might want to look at [git-svn](http://trac.parrot.org/parrot/wiki/git-svn-tutorial) which creates a local git repository that you can commit to and then separately you can commit those changes back to SVN.